# Вставка изображения на форму

Tags: java, netbeans

Подскажите, как в Java вставить картинку в форму при работе в NetBeans.
Читал, что как-то через ресурсы. Подскажите, кто знает.
И как зделать что бы картинки чередовались(менялись)

Answer (score 1):

Вот посмотрите этот туториал: [Handling Images in a Java GUI Application](http://netbeans.org/kb/docs/java/gui-image-display.html).

Comment: А Как можна делать смену картинки в одной lable?

Comment: еще раз вызовите setIcon, но уже с другой картинкой